# How can I fix a java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file error?

Tags: java, macos, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use Sublime Text 2 on my Mac in order to write my code for a class I'm taking. I want to test to make sure I can do this first with a basic program, however I'm coming up with an error when I try to run it. I have the build system set to JavaC, and the code is compiling fine, it's just when I try to run it I get issues. Here are my steps:

```
$ cd Documents/school/algorithms/assignments/
$ javac Hello.java
$ java Hello

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I've tried to research what this means but I'm coming up short. Here is my code for `Hello.java`

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me with this issue it would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: It means that your class file is corrupted. Why? That's not a Java problem. Maybe your disk was full? Try: delete Hello.class, compile again, run again. Check that your disk isn't full first.

Answer (score 3):

Your "Hello.java" file doesn't have any issue at all as I can see.
But the error you are getting `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file` is due to an issue with your class file(byte code).
Actually, there is two type of `ClassFormatError`:

- The first one is "Incompatible magic value" which occurs only when you modify the byte code (add something or delete something) in the `.class` file
- The second one "Truncated class file" which you are getting and the reason behind this error is that the `.class` file doesn't contain any byte code.

So I will suggest you to check your `.class` file to make sure that it contains some code. If it doesn't, save your code to another directory and then compile and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed the same issue in Android Studio `4.1.1`. The error was:

```
> Task :my_module:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
```

Restarting Android Studio, invalidating caches were of no help. The only thing that helped me was upgrading Kotlin version (I had `1.4.10`) to match the Kotlin Plugin one (I have `1.4.20`).

**Project-level `build.gradle`:**

```groovy
buildscript {
    // I've upgraded Kotlin version to match the Kotlin plugin one.
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```